# Compiling .dylib for Mac

Tags: c++, teamspeak

I have a `plugin.cpp`, `plugin.h` and `pluginversion.h`. I need to compile into a .dylib file for the [TeamSpeak MassMove plugin](http://addons.teamspeak.com/directory/addon/miscellaneous-plugins/TS3MassMover.html). I've tried multiple methods of compiling a C++ files and headers into a .dylib, but none have worked. Running OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Just move all files of your plugin into

```
/Applications/TeamSpeak 3 Client.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pluginsdk/src
```

Then (if not open yet) open your Terminal.app and cd to that directory. Afterwards you should open the plugin.cpp file and adjust the paths of the Teamspeak includes (the includes in ' " ') with enough ../.. and include/ in front of the filenames. Now you save and close the plugin.cpp and type

```
g++ -shared plugin.cpp -o PluginName.dylib
```

The last step would be to move the .dylib file to your ../../plugins directory. Now you should be able to start Teamspeak, if it crashes, it's probably worth looking into

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Teamspeak\ 3/logs
```

where all your TeamSpeak3 client-logs get stored.

Hope that helps.